# I installed Telegram but I can't see it in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, telegram

I already installed Telegram through terminal in Ubuntu 16.04   but i can't  see it in app launcher. I used these commands to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

also tried to install it through :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram-desktop
```

but it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
telegram is already the newest version (0.10.16-0ubuntu0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open dash, then type Telegram. If you encounter any issue like Telegram couldn't open desktop version, instead it launch the web version. Run following command :

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

This should make the Telegram Desktop version appear on the Ubuntu Dash.